# How to open links consecutelively from CSV

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open links one-by-one from a CSV-file.
So far I've only managed to launch Chrome. How do you add the data source to the code? After that you should be able to simply open every link as loop.

Thank you!

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LaunchChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\user\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

                driver.get("URL from CSV as Loop");


        }
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve by opening links one by one?

Answer (score 1):

***Please check below piece of code and lets know if it resolved your problem***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class LaunchChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\user\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        readFileLineByLineUsingBufferedReader(driver); 
    }

    public static void readFileLineByLineUsingBufferedReader(WebDriver driver) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CSV_FILE_PATH"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                driver.get(line);
                // You may give some pause here (Thread.sleep(2000));  
                // read next line
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch(IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```